# Declaring a `RECORD[]` variable gets `variable "..." has pseudo-type record[]` error

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, plpgsql, recordtype

I tried to declare the local variable `value` with `RECORD[]` type in a [DO statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) as shown below:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  value RECORD[];
BEGIN
END
$$;
```

But, I got the error below:

> ERROR:  variable "value" has pseudo-type record[]

I referred to these questions and answers but I could not solve the error:

- [postgresql cannot create table with pseudo-type record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44442804/postgresql-cannot-create-table-with-pseudo-type-record)
- [Postgresql: How to work around pseudo-type record errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74143955/postgresql-how-to-work-around-pseudo-type-record-errors)

Actually, I could declare `value` with `RECORD` or `INT[]` type without error as shown below:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  value RECORD;
BEGIN
END
$$;
```

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  value INT[];
BEGIN
END
$$;
```

So, how can I declare `value` with `RECORD[]` type?

Comment: Can you say something more about how you intend to use that `record[]`?

Answer (score 2):

Like the error message says, `record` is a [pseudo-type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-pseudo.html). Note how pseudo-types are absent from this list in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-DECLARATION):

> Arrays of any built-in or user-defined base type, enum type, composite type, range type, or domain can be created.

Some pseudo-types don't make sense as element type of an array to begin with. And `record[]` is just not implemented to be declared in PL/pgSQL. That might change in the future, but don't hold your breath. I don't think it's very useful. [And neither does Tom Lane.](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/716852.1704402127@sss.pgh.pa.us)

I have never had the need for something like `record[]`. Maybe you can use an array based on a registered row type. But, typically, there is a better way. You would have do disclose what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: *"You cannot declare an array based on that."* - [We can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77969634/5298879), and it's [not even our first rodeo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77952634/how-to-create-the-array-of-rows-by-hand-in-postgresql) (or a visit at the zoo of bad ideas).

Comment: This question is about PL/pgSQL. I had added the tag, but the OP removed it again. Maybe OP is not aware that a `DO` statement defaults to `LANGUAGE plpgsql`. Either way, this is 100 % a PL/pgSQL issue. Declaring a variable of type `record[]` is currently not implemented there (even if Postgres can handle it). I clarified my wording a bit and added a link to ongoing work.

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface by saying I agree that you *shouldn't need it*. But can you have it? [You sure can](https://dbfiddle.uk/HZo73TL_):

```sql
DO $do$
DECLARE
  var record:=(null,array[row(1,'a',false),
                          row(2,'b',true),
                          row(3,'c') ] );
  rec record;
BEGIN 
FOREACH rec IN ARRAY var.f2 LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE '%', rec.f2::text;
END LOOP; 
END $do$;
```

Your `record[]` is now inside the second field of that `record` in `var`.

---

If you think about it, a local variable holding an array of records sounds an awful lot like *a temp table*. You could just as well: [(working demo)](https://dbfiddle.uk/hfb0qHaM)

```sql
DO $do$
DECLARE
  r record;
BEGIN
  create temp table my_records (c1 int, c2 text, c3 boolean);
  insert into my_records values (1,'a',false),
                                (2,'b',true);
  for r in select * from my_records loop
     create table if not exists somewhere as select r.c1, r.c2, r.c3 limit 0;
     insert into somewhere select r.c1, r.c2, r.c3;
  end loop;
END $do$;
```